# Automated process to seamlessly loop music

Tags: audio, music, looping, loop

I always loop audio tracks for my daily vlog.

It's like audio track is 3 minutes but I make this audio like 20 minutes.

I just find one point near the beginning that also appears near the end.

Then I do nice 2 cuts and just copy paste this middle part few times.

And I have one start + 10x middle part + 1 end. And a viewer can't even feel this is looped in this way or something.

---

And

My question is...

Can I automate this? Some plugin? for premiere or something?

Maybe some program or application that will do this for me?

Music Looper? Audio Track Smart Looper?

Some script? Maybe AI system?

I just wanna don't do this all the time, ep by ep, audio track after another audio track.

It's the thing that I do every single day.

So is this possible? To somehow automate this process :)?

Comment: If you are looking to loop this audio for a VLog, why can't you just play it directly in your DAW and let it loop in the background?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a very simple process that you can use to loop music, which only requires a single edit. It does require some skill to locate the correct edit points and to implement the required crossfade correctly.

1. Identify a segment of music that you wish to loop
2. Make a rough selection around the range
3. You will need to create 3 markers within the range:

   1. Start
   2. Middle
   3. End.

If your music has a beat, it is usually easiest to create these markers on a beat.

Once you have these markers created, you will be joining the "Start" marker with the "End" marker, using an edit, and then splitting the whole range at the "Middle".

1. Trim the clip down to the Start and End markers so that the "Start" and "End" are the first and last samples.
2. Split the clip at the "Middle" marker. You will now have two clips. One which represents "Start" to "Middle" and the other "Middle" to "End".
3. If you are using "protools" select "Shuffle" mode and then drag the first clip to the end so that you switch the order of the clips.
4. Now, your "End" marker samples will be butted up against the "Start" marker samples.
5. Put in a crossfade so that the join sounds natural
6. Consolidate all the regions to a single region.

Your loopable region is complete.

It is unlikely you will be able to automate this entirely as there will be human input required in identifying the marker points, but once you have those it is a very straightforward process which could easily be automated.

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is a few years old now, but it looks to be a duplicate of a question posted on [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/questions/1333540/seamless-audio-track-music-loop-auto-automatic-ai-script/1784465#1784465). I answered there after finding something that worked for me, so I'll answer here too.

[PyMusicLooper](https://github.com/arkrow/PyMusicLooper) is a free, open source "python script for repeating music seamlessly and endlessly, by automatically finding the best loop points."

From the GitHub [project page](https://github.com/arkrow/PyMusicLooper):

> **Features**:
>
> - Find loop points within any music file (if they exist).
> - Supports a large set of different audio formats, and all the popular ones (MP3, OGG, M4A, FLAC, WAV, etc).
> - Play the music file endlessly and seamlessly with the best discovered loop.
> - Export to intro/loop/outro sections for editing or seamless playback within any music player that supports gapless playback.
> - Export loop points in samples to a text file (e.g. for use in creating custom themes with seamlessly looping audio).

You can even batch process:

> Export intro/loop/outro sections and loop points of all the songs in the current directory and its subdirectories, to a folder called "Music Loops", processing 4 tracks concurrently.
>
> ```
> pymusiclooper -ret . -o "Music Loops" -n 4
> ```

Answer (score 0):

I would say no software exists that automatically finds the best spot to loop a track. However there is a DAW that could make it easier for you after you find your looping section. That program is called Ableton Live and you can set sections of your song and then use a midi switch to either loop a section or move on to the next section without doing a lot of copy and pasting. Or just do it from the computer.

[This](https://youtu.be/gS6F_W-U8lE) video sort of shows what I am talking about.

Answer (score 0):

You could check out something like [Sonic Pi](https://sonic-pi.net/) which allows you to script your own music. Not necessarily what you're looking for, but at least it allows you to create sequences which can then be looped, or gradually evolve into something else.